# std::result::Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error> cannot be formatted with the default formatter

Tags: rust

Im new to rust and im trying to grab the requests response body, my current code is:

```
let client = reqwest::Client::new();
let response_text = client.get("google").send();
println!("{}", response_text);
```

But this produces the error

```
std::result::Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short version

Use `"{:?}"` instead of `"{}"` for debugging output.

### Long version

I had to modify your code to get the same error message:

```
pub fn dummy() {
    let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
    let response_text = client.get("google").send();
    println!("{}", response_text);
}
```

which uses the blocking API rather than the async API. The async API gives a similar but slightly more complicated error.

The full error message is:

```
error[E0277]: `std::result::Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, reqwest::Error>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:20
  |
5 |     println!("{}", response_text);
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::result::Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, reqwest::Error>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, reqwest::Error>`
  = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
  = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

The first line gives the underlying cause `std::result::Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, reqwest::Error>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`.

The problem is that formatting with "{}" requires an object to support `std::fmt::Display`, and a Result object doesn't support that. (You can check this by looking through the list of traits it implements at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html )

`Result` does implement `std::fmt::Debug` so long as both of its parameters do,
as is the case here.
This is the trait required to be formattable with `"{:?}"` rather than `{}`.

If you don't want debugging output you need to work a little harder to get at the content. You'll want something like

```
   match response_text {
       Err(e) => eprintln!("Error: {:?}", e);
       Ok(v) => println!("Body: {}", v.text().unwrap();
   }
```

But even this doesn't handle the case with non-UTF8 input correctly, and the unwrap will panic.